# What framework for learning ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net

Having been working around Unix and some Java for many years and then some XPages I wish to move towards .NET and mainly to ASP.NET using C#, but from what I have found so far there seems to be a dramatic change in the .NET framework after version 3.5 moved to version 4.0 of the framework.  So my question is in regards to obtaining employment or contracting in ASP.NET is it advisable to start learning at version 3.5 of the framework or version 4.0?  Is there any books someone can recommend?  I usually prefer the Apress technical book publications

Comment: I've been learning asp.net since framework 2.0. I don't think there was dramatic change from 3.5 to 4.0. I recommend you to learn the latest version of asp.net (there's no reason to learn an older version), that is 4.5

Comment: You can start with framework 4.0. 
http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/netframeworklist

Comment: Unfortunately, the subject of the question is explicitly off-topic by the rules of SO. But to answer your question: IMHO it's best if you start learning from version 4.0 and on (preferably around version 4.6, the current one, with version 5.0 coming), unless you plan to work on maintaining existing applications. Of course, despite the occasional drastic changes between its versions, it's pretty much the same framework and all of them are in the same vein, anyway.

Comment: There's no reason to learn 3.5 (release date 2007) unless you'll be maintaining 3.5 sites. Anyways, 4.0 and 3.5 really aren't very different. As far as books recommendations, that's off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks to all for your feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there was dramatic change from 3.5 to 4.0
I recommend: Apress Beginning ASP.NET 4 In C Sharp
best regards